# Subdomains loading index.php for web root

Tags: php, wordpress, nginx

I'm trying to setup nginx for local dev/testing. Subdomains load up the main index.php and I cannot figure out why. The problem is that nowingnews.localhost.com and wasob.mylocalhost.com both load the index.php of http://mylocalhost/index.php.

Here is the virtualhost config for nowingnews.mylocalhost.com

```
server { 

#Nginx should listen on port 80 for requests to yoursite.com
listen 80; 
server_name nowingnews.mylocalhost.com; 

#Create access and error logs in /var/log/nginx
access_log /var/log/nginx/nowingnews.access_log; 
error_log /var/log/nginx/nowingnews.error_log debug; 

root /var/www/html/nowingnews; 

 #location / {
  #try_files $uri $uri/ /nowingnews/index.php;
  #}

#Specifies that Nginx is looking for .php files
location ~ /.*\.php$ {
include fastcgi_params;
fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+?\.php)(/.*)$;
#if (!-f $document_root$fastcgi_script_name) {
#    return 404;
#}

fastcgi_index /index.php;

# SCRIPT_FILENAME parameter is used for PHP FPM determining
#  the script name. If it is not set in fastcgi_params file,
# i.e. /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params or in the parent contexts,
# please comment off following line:
fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;

 # Mitigate https://httpoxy.org/ vulnerabilities
fastcgi_param HTTP_PROXY "";

 # include the fastcgi_param setting
include /etc/nginx/fastcgi.conf;
fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
} 
}
```

And here is the default config

```
server { 

#Nginx should listen on port 80 for requests to yoursite.com
listen 80; 
server_name localhost; 

#Create access and error logs in /var/log/nginx
access_log /var/log/nginx/default.access_log; 
error_log /var/log/nginx/default.error_log crit; 

root /var/www/html/;
#The homepage of your website is a file called index.php 
index index.php index.htm index.html; 

#Specifies that Nginx is looking for .php files
location ~ /.*\.php$ {
fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+?\.php)(/.*)$;

# Mitigate https://httpoxy.org/ vulnerabilities
fastcgi_param HTTP_PROXY "";
include fastcgi_params;

# SCRIPT_FILENAME parameter is used for PHP FPM determining
#  the script name. If it is not set in fastcgi_params file,
# i.e. /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params or in the parent contexts,
# please comment off following line:
fastcgi_index index.php;
fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME   $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
}

}

include  "/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*";
```

Comment: https://paste.ngx.cc/7e499702ea18a24e

Comment: please include details _within the question_, not at external links, which can change or die, or people may not wish to click on them. You can use the "edit" button to change your question. Thanks.

Comment: Dont know NGINX, but as both your `server` configs use the same domain name and the same `root` directory, how are you distinguishing between your 2 environments?

Comment: Maybe what you really need to do is Read the manual

Comment: Use `listen 80;` instead of `listen xxx:80;` and make sure that your `server_name` matches the name of the server. In your question they **do not match!**

Comment: I've updated this to reflect changes. It is still doing the same thing, I do not understand why it's happening at all.